# How to make evil-mode completion case sensitive?

Tags: evil, completion

While this answer ([How to make auto-completion case sensitive?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27718/how-to-make-auto-completion-case-sensitive) - `ac-ignore-case`) works in some cases.

Using evil mode on its own.
Adding `(setq ac-ignore-case nil)` to `~/.emacs` doesn't make completion case sensitive. (Pressing Ctrl-N in evil mode).

From looking into it this calls `evil-complete-next`.

Checked the source but didn't see any options to adjust.

Can this be made to be case sensitive?

Comment: Check out `evil-complete-next-func` which `evil-complete-next` documentation points at - this uses `dabbrev` by default. So maybe this: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7464/case-sensitivity-of-word-completion-using-dabbrev (not tested).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evil mode uses `dabbrev`, to make autocomplete case sensitive, set this in your emacs config.

```
(setq dabbrev-case-fold-search nil)
```

See: [case-sensitivity of word completion using dabbrev](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7464) for details.

*thanks to @VanLaser for the hint.*

Comment: Maybe that's just me but I also had to set `(case-fold-search nil)`. Try it if dabbrev-case-fold-search didn't work